# Traverse a Table to Find the Optimal Solution

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

The topic is the Knapsack Problem.

I have to write a function that returns the best items, meaning the items that are chosen. As an input, it receives the table my first function returned and the list of items.

```
def make_table(items, max_wt):
    table = [[(0, 0) for x in range(max_wt+ 1)] for y in range(len(items) + 1)]
    for i in range(1, len(items) + 1):
        for j in range(1, max_wt + 1):  # lines: lists every item
            (vl, wt) = items[i - 1]  # rows: lists every weight
            # if weight of the current item exceeds current max possible weight, take the value from the above cell
            if wt > j: 
                table[i][j] = (table[i - 1][j][0], 0)
            # if not, compare the last optimal solution with the new (potentially) best solution
            else:
                last_opt = table[i - 1][j][0]
                new_opt = table[i - 1][j - wt][0] + vl
                if last_opt >= new_opt:  # Choose whichever has the highest value
                    table[i][j] = (last_opt, 0) # flag 1 if used to preserve the max value, 0 if not
                else:
                    table[i][j] = (new_opt, 1)
    return table

def run_table(table, items):
item_ct = len(items)
manifest = [0] * item_ct
# Start at end of table and retrace steps back to an empty pack.
# The table is organized by item (rows) and weight (columns).

soln_wt = maximum_wt    # Weight of the remaining solution 
for item_no in range(item_ct, 0, -1):
    print("Check item", item_no, "\t weight", soln_wt)
    wt, used = table[item_no][soln_wt]

    if used:
        manifest[item_no-1] = 1
        soln_wt -= items[item_no-1][1]

return manifest

val_wt = [(3,4),(1,1),(4,5),(3,4),(2,2)]
maximum_wt = 8
T = createTable(val_wt, maximum_wt)

best_vl = T[-1][-1][0]  # should be the maximum value ( = 7 )
print("Best packing", best_vl)
L = run_table(T, val_wt)  # should return [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
print(L)
```

How can I traverse this table to recover the items that are included in the optimum solution?

Comment: Knapsack attacks are quite plentiful on this site and elsewhere.  How does your variation of these algorithms not fall into any of those categories?  Please compare/contrast and show how far you get with those solutions.

Comment: I *did* read more.  I scanned your code; I *think* I follow the general flow of the table construction.  Perhaps I'm missing the point of your question -- does this table embody the *solution*, and all you need to do is somehow traverse it to find the components that comprise that solution?

Comment: There are other knapsack algorithms that deal with tagged matrices; tuples look to me to be an implementation detail, rather than a differentiator.

Comment: Also, can you explain the table algorithm in *your* words ... I just found a disconnection in what I thought I knew about it.  The generic variable names aren't helping ...

Comment: In the final solution ... isn't [1, 1, 0, 0, 1] also a valid output from `bestChoice`?

Comment: @Prune I added some comments to explain it. LastOPT is the last best solution, NewOPT the possible new best solution. Of course if the item weight > sum of weights we just take the previous value without even comparing anything.

Comment: @Prune And yes, bestChoice uses the table and list of items to get the solution. I don't quite know how to traverse the table to get there.. and I [1, 1, 0, 0, 1] would result in a total value of 6. The first part of the tuple is the value, the second the weight.

Comment: The 1st and 4th items have identical value and weight; they should be interchangeable in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at the lower-right corner of your table, you need to backtrack through the creation logic.  The general rule is:

- If the current cell is tagged `1`, then add the current item to the solution set, and move left `weight` cells.
- Otherwise, the current item is *not* in the solution set
- Move up one row

Here's how it works for the given case:

- cell [5, 8] (a.k.a. [-1, -1]) is tagged `1`; add item 5 to the solution set (now [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]) and move left by the weight `items[5,1]`, which is 2.  Also move up one row to [4, 6]
- cell [4, 6] is tagged `0`; item 4 is not in the solution.  Move up one row.
- cell [3, 6] is tagged `1`; add item 3 to the solution (now [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]) and move left by the weight of 5, then up one row.
- cell [2, 1] is tagged `1`; add item 2 to the solution (now [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]) and move left by the weight of 1, then up one row.
- cell [1, 1] is tagged `0`; item 1 is not in the solution.  Move up one row.

With no more items to check, we're done.  The solution is 01101.

---

Code

```
def run_table(table, items):
    item_ct = len(items)
    manifest = [0] * item_ct
    # Start at end of table and retrace steps back to an empty pack.
    # The table is organized by item (rows) and weight (columns).

    soln_wt = maxWeight    # Weight of the remaining solution 
    for item_no in range(item_ct, 0, -1):
        print("Check item", item_no, "\t weight", soln_wt)
        wt, used = table[item_no][soln_wt]

        if used:
            manifest[item_no-1] = 1
            soln_wt -= items[item_no-1][1]

    return manifest

val_wt = [(3,4),(1,1),(4,5),(3,4),(2,2)]
maxWeight = 8
T = createTable(val_wt, maxWeight)

bestValue = T[-1][-1][0]  # should be the maximum value ( = 7 )
print("Best packing", bestValue)
L = run_table(T, val_wt)  # should return [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
print(L)
```

Output:

```
Best packing 7
Check item 5     weight 8
Check item 4     weight 6
Check item 3     weight 6
Check item 2     weight 1
Check item 1     weight 0
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: I tried to implement that into the original post.. but I got kind of lost in the middle. There are a few steps I'm definitely missing or did wrong but that's all I have for now.

Comment: So soln_wt is how much space we have left in the knapsack?

Comment: I also went ahead and made my first function more pythonic. Any suggestions on how to make it shorter/neater?

Comment: Correct; that's "solution weight".  Once we've accounted for each item, the problem reduces to items earlier in the list, with that remaining weight.

Comment: Improving the code would be a separate question on another site, such as CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: Please note that your question, as currently posted, no longer fits the issues we've discussed.  This damages the question for archive purposes -- keep in mind the over-arching charter of Stack Overflow.  You should put the question back to its valid form for this discussion, and raise you follow-on questions elsewhere as appropriate.